# cordova icons and splashscreen not working

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Am facing a dilemma here.My cordova app works fine however the icons and splashscreen dont , they reflect to default cordova icons and splashscreen .
My config.xml is as below , the icon and image exist in my directory path, but they are not being reflected . The cordova splashcreen plugin is also installed correctly . what might i be doing wrong ?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.something.portal" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Someapp</name>
    <description>
        Someapp
    </description>
    <author email="cliffjimmy27@gmail.com" href="https://gmail.com">
        Obonyo Jimmycliff
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="cdvfile://*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <icon src="res/icon.png" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.6.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.4.0" />
</widget>
```

Comment: What Cordova version did you use ?
Recently I have to downgrade from 6.4.x to 6.3.1 (Don't really know why, but it work)

Comment: am using 6.4.x , mmh let me try that

Comment: If that work, let me know :). So I can post it as an answer.

Comment: sure kindly do i the mean time also dont forget to upote if you think the question to be usefll  :-)

Comment: Have you also tried to remove the platform-wrapper-element(android,ios) and define the platform as attribut with each splash-element? Just like [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml).

Comment: @Blauharley i see you are using phonegap instead of cordova , what version of cordova would tht be ?

Comment: @JimmyObonyoAbor I actually use cordova as well, that example  should show of what I meant. As we all know there is little difference between these two frameworks, so I can use as least those splash-platform-attributes almost in the same way as I would use them with phonegap. Unfortunately I dont know how you can determine the cordova version from the phonegap version.

Comment: @Blauharley thanks let be check this out , just to suggest kindly put a yor suggestion as an answer to help in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Dev-Versions:

- cordova-version: 6.0.0
- ionic-version: 1.7.14

Please not that I just can speak for myself:

I just created a testapp and although the icon worked I got the same problem with the splash-images too. It turned out that the preference *SplashScreenDelay* was set too low. When you create an cordova-project by using ionic, the *SplashScreenDelay* is assigned with 2 seconds(2000) that in my case was is too low. As soon as I saw the first page the 2 seconds were over.

According to [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide/platforms/android/config.html) the default is 5 seconds but when I removed *SplashScreenDelay*, I saw no splash-image either but as soon as I assigned 5 seconds to *SplashScreenDelay* it worked. I also noticed that when I reopened my app there was no splash-image either after closing the app via [settings](http://www.wikihow.com/Close-Apps-on-Android) it was shown again. Lets say its strange here.

Therefore I would like to recommend to use the [cordova-plugin-splashscreen](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) plugin to make sure that your splash-image is always shown no matter whether you assigned a low value to *SplashScreenDelay* or not.

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.testapp128533" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>testapp</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/>
  <icon src="icon.png" />
  <platform name="android">
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-hdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-ldpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-mdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png" />
    <splash density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png" />
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Project-Directory:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cordova does not support all ios devices. To generate all possible icons and splash screens with one single file I can only recommend using [`cordova-icon`](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon) and [`cordova-splash`](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-splash)

The instructions are easy to follow and I had everything up and running within 5 minutes.